# Perfect complexes and RGamma(X,F) without mentioning derived categories

Tags: derived-categories, derived-functors, ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-modules

Let $A$ be a commutative noetherian ring.

Let $K_{parf}(A)$ be the full subcategory of the homotopy category $K(A)$ of $A$-modules whose objects are bounded complexes of finitely generated projective $A$-modules. The functor $K_{parf}(A) \longrightarrow D(A)$ is fully faithful and we denote its essential image by $D_{parf}(A)$. An object of $D_{parf}(A)$ is called a  **perfect complex**.

I have to give a talk about the Trace formula on tuesday and the audience and me are not so comfortable with derived categories (yet). (See below for what we want to do this tuesday.)

**Question 1.** Is a complex of $A$-modules perfect iff it is quasi-isomorphic to a bounded complex of finitely generated projective $A$-modules? Is there some condition involving ``homotopy'' missing?

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a locally constant finite sheaf of finitely generated projective $A$-modules on a finite type separated $k$-scheme $X$.

This defines an object $$K=\ldots \longrightarrow 0\longrightarrow \mathcal{F} \longrightarrow 0 \longrightarrow \ldots $$ of the derived category $D(X,A)$ of sheaves of $A$-modules.

**Question 2.** Can one explicitly write down a complex representing $R\Gamma_c(X,\mathcal{F})$? (One may assume $X$ is proper over $k$ for simplicity.)

One can show that $R\Gamma_c(X,\mathcal{F})$ is a perfect complex after identifying $A$-modules with sheaves of $A$-modules on $\textrm{Spec} \ k$. If the answer to Question 2 is positive, I could avoid introducing derived  categories on tuesday.

[ADDED]

To prove Grothendieck's generalized Lefschetz trace formula, it suffices to prove the following statement.

**Theorem.** Let $X_0$ be a smooth affine geometrically integral curve over $\mathbf{F}_q$ and let $\Lambda$ be a finite ring which gets killed by a power of a prime number $\ell$ invertible in $\mathbf{F}_q$. Suppose that  $X_0(k) = \emptyset$. Then, for any locally constant finite sheaf  $\mathcal{F}$  of finite projective $\Lambda$-modules, we have that $$ 0= \textrm{Tr}(\textrm{Frob}^\ast, R\Gamma_c(X,K)).$$

So one has to do three things:

1. Understand the statement above.
2. Show that this statement implies the Trace formula
3. Prove the statement above.

1 and 3 don't really need the language of derived categories, I believe. That's why I asked this question.  Next week we will take care of 2 after introducing derived categories.

Comment: For Question 2, I guess it might be simpler if one assumes that X is smooth rather than proper (when proving the trace formula one can shrink X to open subspaces), so that one can use Poincaré duality to identify $R\Gamma_c(X,F)$ with the dual complex of $R\Gamma(X,F^{\vee}(d)[2d]).$ Anyway I think it's worth mentioning derived categories in the étale cohom. workshop, if no one is assigned to discussed it in detail. For Q1, I remember SGA 4.5 proved something related. You may find some sections in chapter 2 of K-W useful, too.

Comment: Next week someone will take care of the ''derived categorical'' part of the proof. Please see my edit to see what our plan is. As you said, we can assume $X$ to be smooth in the proof of the Trace formula. Therefore, we can use your suggestion. The only problem is that we haven't done Poincare duality yet and I also don't know what you mean by RΓ(X,F∨(d)[2d])...What is K-W? 

Comment: By the way, for the proof of the above statement (see Edit) one doesn't really need to know what RGamma_c(X,K) is...In fact, one uses Weil's classical trace formula for smooth projective curves and combines this with some results about traces over noncommutative rings (such as Z/l^nZ[G]). Just something funny I wanted to point out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 1 the answer is yes, in fact the question is tautological. As for question 2 (I assume that $R\Gamma_c$ stands for the sections with compact support which in the case of proper $X$ coincide with $R\Gamma$), of course you can use any standard complex, for example you can use Cech complex.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, one can do the following. Let C be the Cech complex of F (associated to some cofinal open covering). Then C is quasi-isomorphic to RGamma_c(X,F)? This would be great!

Comment: I meant f_*F, where f:X-->Y is a compactification. More precisely, given a projective curve Y over k and a locally constant sheaf F on the Y_{et}, do we have that RGamma(Y,F) is quasi-isomorphic to the Cech complex of F (associated to a cover by two open affines in Y)?

Comment: I don't see why the Cech complex (attached to an etale open covering) will do, i.e. the assoc. spectral sequence won't degenerate in general. Take $X$ to be a proj. curve covered by two opens, and $F$ is the constant sheaf. Then there's no way to get a rank-$2g$ space out of the Cech complex.

Comment: You're right. Let me say that I don't really need to write down an explicit complex. I just want to define RGamma(X,F). I could take an injective resolution  for F, say I. Then what does RGamma(X,F) become? Is it the complex you get after taking global sections?

Comment: Yes, $R\Gamma(X,F),$ for $F$ bounded below, can be computed as (i.e. is quasi-isom. to) the complex $\Gamma(I^{\bullet}).$ The definition of $R\Gamma(X,-)$ fits into the general framework of derived categories and derived functors (i.e. some universal 2-properties), and on $D^+(X)$ one can use injective resolutions to "compute" (not in the practical sense, I think). On the full $D(X)$ one can use K-injective resolutions (and K-flat resol. for left derived functors); see Spaltenstein's "Resolutions of unbounded complexes".